# Selectively pull/track files in git

Tags: git

I am using git for a large group project, but only part of the project is relevant to me. I would like to be able to specify which files I want to keep track of (that is, have copies of on my local computer). My preference would be to be able to ignore all the updates etc. on these files and effectively act as if they don't exist, if that is at all possible.

I know how to use gitignore https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ to not keep track of files (for example, don't track all *.aux files created by latex), but I couldn't figure out how to use this to not track files that others need tracked.

I am a new to git and a bad programmer - so complicated fixes will most likely end up with me breaking something. If it can be done simply that would be great - if not, knowing that it can't will also be helpful.

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the local files, which are tracked by the branch, to the appropriate `.gitignore` file should do the trick.  However, if you have already made changes to some of these local files which you want to ignore, then you must also run the following command for each file:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [<filename>]
```

Running this `git update-index` command should allow you to push your local branch with changes in the tracked files you want to ignore.  Git should ignore these changes and they should not show up in the commit, but all other changes to tracked files will be present.